# How to requeue message queue if something happen wrong

Tags: magento2, message-queue

I am implementing message queue for my system. I want to know that how can i requeue any queue if something goes wrong or suppose my api didnt give me response as i wish so i want to send that message again in requeue.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/run-as-root/magento2-message-queue-retry pretty much enables you to do this:

> It gives the possibility to process the same queue message more than once, utilizing The RabbitMQ's dead letter exchange feature.